# Snowflake- Export results as CSV and send in email

Tags: python, email, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to set up a task in snowflake that will select everything from a given table and convert this output into a CSV and then email this CSV to some designated recipients.

```
with pretty_email_results as procedure()
returns string
language python
packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python', 'tabulate')
handler = 'x'
runtime_version=3.8
as
$$
def x(session):
    printed = session.sql(
        "select * from table"
      ).to_pandas().to_markdown()
      
    session.call('system$send_email',
        'my_email_int',
        'test@email.com',
        'Email Alert: Task A has finished.',
        printed)
$$
call pretty_email_results();
```

I want to be able to convert printed into a CSV, whereas right now it just emails the output as a block of text.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the `to_csv()` function instead of `to_markdown()`?

```
printed = session.sql(
        "select * from table"
      ).to_pandas().to_csv()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html